# How to find an optimal location on a surface with the given probability distribution?

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, optimization

Imagine a fisherman wants to catch maximum number of fish on a shore. The length of his fishing rod is $L$, half of the shore width.

[image]

The shore (where the fisherman can stand) is the white space. The blue space is the lake. The color intensity shows the probability distribution of fish, meaning that the there is a higher chance to catch fish in the middle. However, our lake has also some sharks (believe it or not), which are uniformly distributed in the lake. So, the fisherman can not get arbitrarily close to the lake. The closer he is, the higher penalty for example. The safest place is on the bottom corners (not a hard constraint, though.)

How can I formulate this problem into an optimization problem? What is the general mathematical term to describe this problem? (Asking this question to be able to search and study it, later.) How to insert a different probability distribution?